# How do I approximate a staircase function (rounding) with triangle wave?

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, approximation

[image]

The rounding function may look like this. I think I might be able to simulate this function with $\text{trianglewave}(x)+x$, some thing like that, but I don't know how to do it.

My final goal is to come up with any functions that can approximate this rounding function while it is differentiable (a smooth approximation).

Comment: A triangle wave is continuous, while the rounding function is discontinuous, so this will not work. A sawtooth wave would do better.

Comment: @Moo I just want to approximate this rounding method, I thought this might be a good way of doing it. (I might be wrong).

Comment: @Rahul I think maybe the continuity is not my main focus, I just want to get some function that looks close enough to the rounding function while it is differentiable.

Comment: Triangle waves are not differentiable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a suggestion. Set $n$ to a large constant value, and let
\begin{align}
h(t,c) &= \frac{n}{\sqrt\pi} e^{-n^2 (t-c)^2}, \\
g(t)   &= \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty h\left(t,k+\tfrac12\right), \\
f(x)   &= \int_0^x g(t)\,dt \\
&= \frac12 \sum_{k=0}^\infty
      \left(\mathrm{erf}\left(n \left(x-k-\tfrac12 \right)\right)
          + \mathrm{erf}\left(n \left(x+k+\tfrac12 \right)\right)\right).
\end{align}
For $n=100$, the function $f$ has a graph like [the one this link produces](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=graph+%5B-Erf%5B50(5-2x)%5D-Erf%5B50(3-2x)%5D-Erf%5B50(1-2x)%5D%2BErf%5B50(1%2B2x)%5D%2BErf%5B50(3%2B2x)%5D%2BErf%5B50(5%2B2x)%5D%5D%2F2), except that it continues stepping
up or down indefinitely in each direction.
(In the linked graph, only the first few terms of $f(t)$ are counted.)

This graph has none of the extra little "bumps" that the Fourier series
has, and it is differentiable.

Comment: Interesting, since error function looks so similar to sigmoid function, can I use sigmoid function to produce the similar result?

Comment: Anything that represents the integral of an "impulse" should work, I think, as long as you translate and scale it appropriately.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the answer of Taozi, approximates with Fourier series are shown below. Of course, the accuracy depends on the number $N$ of terms :

[image]

Note : A typo corrected.

Comment: Awesome! Since I've not exposed to any signal processing before, may I ask what is the insight behind it that makes you write the Fourier series in this form? I would be appreciated if you can include more details regarding how you discover this in your answer so people can learn more from it. Thank you!

Comment: Let SC$(x)$ denotes the staircase function. It is easy to see that $x−$SC$(x)$ is a sawtooth wave. Applying the calculus for the coefficients of Fourier series leads to the above result. See : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series  . $a_n=0$ and $b_n=2\int_{-1/2}^{1/2}(-x)\sin(2\pi nx)dx=\frac{(-1)^n}{\pi n}$ .

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comment, you can not approximate a discontinuous function with a continuous one; unless an infinite series is used. The triangle wave in some sense can be considered as a "sharpened" sine function. You can plot $\sin(2\pi x)$ and TriangleWave[x] (referred as $T(x)$ hereafter) in Mathematica to see what I mean. And $T(n x)$ form an orthogonal basis just like $\sin(2 \pi n x)$ over interval $[0, 1]$.

Then you can expand any periodic function in terms of $T(n x)$. In your case the function has to be "decomposed" first. I will illustrate steps with the standard floor function.

1. Remove the linear component and subtract the mean value, so the transformed function is periodic and oscillation around $x$ axis with equal amplitude. This is called "de-trend" and "de-mean" in signal processing.

$$f(x) = floor(x)-x+1/2$$

2. Expand f(x) as:
   $$f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n T(n x)$$
3. Find $a_n$:
   $$ a_n = \frac{\int_0^1 f(x) T(n x) dx}{\int_0^1 T(n x)^2} = \frac{3}{8 n} $$
4. Transform back (add mean and linear component):
   $$floor(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  \frac{3}{8 n} T(n x) + x - 1/2$$

   - Figure using 10 triangle waves:

[image: Triangle wave approximation of floor function]

Comment: I have to point out that sadly such a series with $n$ terms introduces $O(n^2)$ new sharp corners.

Comment: Thank you so much! What do you mean by "sharp" here? Is the sharp corner differentiable?

Comment: @omg-256 I mean the sharp "turns" of triangle wave functions. For example, $T(x)$ (of a tilted "z" shape) has two of them in [0, 1], $T(2x)$ has 4, $T(nx)$ has $2n$. And a sum of $T(i \cdot x)$ for $i$ from 1 to n has $O(n^2)$ of them in [0, 1].